# Problems to validate empty date field with extbase

Tags: extbase, typo3-8.x

Why did Extbase throws an exception if my start date field is empty. If the date has the wrong format, the validation works. But an empty value shows this:

**Uncaught TYPO3 Exception ... Events::setEnd() must be an instance of DateTime, null given ...**

What is wrong with the following code in my model?

```
    /**
     * start
     *
     * @var \DateTime
     * @validate NotEmpty
     * @validate(type="DateTime", options={"locale"="de_DE"})
     */
    protected $start;
```

And here is my TCA

```
    'start' => [
        'exclude' => false,
        'label' => 'Start',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'input',
            'renderType' => 'inputDateTime',
            'size' => 10,
            'eval' => 'datetime',
            'default' => time()
        ],
    ],
```

Cache cleared, typo3temp folder deleted.

> **UPDATE:** 
>   Perhaps the error is in my initializeUpdateAction() where i have to set the date format?

```
    public function initializeUpdateAction() {

        $user = $this->request->getArgument('feUsers');
        $events = $user['events'];
        if( is_array($events) ) {
            foreach ($events as $i => $event) {
                $this->arguments->getArgument('feUsers')
                    ->getPropertyMappingConfiguration()->forProperty('events.'.$i.'.start')
                    ->setTypeConverterOption(
                        'TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Property\\TypeConverter\\DateTimeConverter',
                        \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Property\TypeConverter\DateTimeConverter::CONFIGURATION_DATE_FORMAT,
                        'd.m.Y'
                    );
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

enhance your validation:

```
 'eval' => 'datetime,int',
```

an empty date field is represented with `0`, which is no valid date format.